# help on Distinct in Select

Tags: java, sql, select, distinct

I can't figure out where the error in this SQL request, can you please help me.
i want display list of projet that the projet.idchef=ac.getid(); and Distinct on RefProjet,

i try this way,

```
 rs =c.selection("SELECT distinct Refprojet,idpro,NomProjet  FROM projet,user where projet.iduser=user.id AND projet.IdChef='"+ac.getid()+"'");
     while(rs.next())
     {
             String num =  rs.getString("idpro");
             String nom = rs.getString("NomProjet");
             String ref  = rs.getString("IdProjet");
             jComboBox2.addItem(new RF(nom,ref,num));
     }  } catch (Exception ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and this i try this way also

```
...

     rs =c.selection("SELECT Distinct (RefProjet) FROM ( SELECT idpro,NomProjet,RefProjet  from projet  Where projet.idChef='"+ac.getid()+"') as T");
 while(rs.next())
 {
         String num =  rs.getString("idpro");
         String nom = rs.getString("NomProjet");
         String ref  = rs.getString("IdProjet");
         jComboBox2.addItem(new RF(nom,ref,num));
 }  } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and many other but nothing work,

how can i do ?!

Please help and thanks

Comment: In other words, Zero-dev, tell us what errors you're getting, and what research you've done to understand them. Are you getting an exception? What type?

Comment: in the first try  it repeat the line displayed and in he second  it return error : `java.sql.SQLException: Column 'idpro' not found`. for this line `String num =  rs.getString("idpro");`

Comment: You do not appear to be returning `idpro` from your second SQL statement. I highly recommend fine-tuning your SQL from a SQL management tool.

Comment: you are only selecting RefProjet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try debugging your SQL using an access tool first (e.g. SQL Server Management Studio, SQL Plus, etc.). Once you know your SQL is correct, then bring it in Java program.

When you have multiple layers, it's always good to isolate the problem to one of those layers. In your case, you need to understand whether the problem is in your SQL, or your in the way your Java programming is using the data access tools.

Comment: Thanks a have try many request and i finally have have the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT refproject,idpro,NomProjet  
FROM projet,user 
where projet.iduser=user.id 
AND projet.IdChef='"+ac.getid()+"'")
AND Refprojet in (select distinct(Refprojet) from project);
```

Comment: i try it but stil display with repeat RefProjet